# Solving $z^4-2iz-i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to the world of complex numbers. I've been going through a few problems in the Complex Numbers: A to Z book. I'm stuck at this problem:

> $z^7-2iz^4-iz^3-2=0$

I've managed to simplify the equation to

$z^3(z^4-2iz-i) = 2$

$z = 2^{1/3}$

I am not able to solve

$z^4-2iz-i$. Any hints or clues are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you assume that $z=\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a solution and what do you even mean by $\sqrt[3]{2}$ (there are three possible values)?

Comment: @PeterForeman Are you implying that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a solution?

Comment: Yes. It is not a solution.

Comment: @PeterForeman Hm. Why not?

Comment: Because plugging it in your equation we would get$$2(2^{4/3}-2i\cdot2^{1/3}-i)=2$$which is clearly not true.

Comment: it may help to first put $z=x+iy$ and attempt to group real and complex terms together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $z^7-2iz^4-iz^3-2=0$ reduces to

$$z^4(z^3-2i)-i(z^3-2i)=0$$

or

> $$(z^3-2i)(z^4-i)=0$$

which is easy to solve.

Comment: Interesting. But how were you able to think of this reduction?

Comment: It may be helpful to show "how" one could find this.

Comment: @NoChance, you are right. I will add up some details...

Comment: @NoLand'sMan, thanks. My method was similar to that of the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!!

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I will be able to accept it as the answer in a few minutes. Also are you aware of any websites/books where I can practice more of such problems?

Comment: I think the Stewart's book **Calculus I** has a good chapter on complex numbers.